# How to slide to perform clicks android

Tags: android, button, drag, multi-touch, slide

I'm trying to make an application that the user can slide or drag the finger across a set of buttons to perform a click. I've tried `onTouch` with `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` but I can't seem to get it to work. The buttons just don't press at all. Here's the code :

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
    if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.key1:
            key1.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key2:
            key2.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key3:
            key3.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key4:
            key4.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key5:
            key5.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key6:
            key6.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key7:
            key7.performClick();
            break;
        case R.id.key8:
            key8.performClick();
            break;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So... the application registers a click if a user slides his / her thumb across all buttons ? Is that the intent (no pun intended)

Comment: Yes but it does not register any clicks on the buttons with the code above

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off capturing the key events on all those buttons and then performing some sort of sum on each one. For example

Key1 = 1
key2 = 1+2
key3 = 1+2+3
...

When you reach keyx, you can check if the sum matches your expectation. If it does, the user probably swiped his / her finger across the buttons. Use some sort of timing by which keyx must be pressed and the numbers must add up to N. That will avoid the user pressing button3 and then coming back to button1 etc and still registering a click.

If you want to register a click on each button, set their onclick listeners and ensure that the buttons themselves are clickable (they should already be).

Comment: The buttons are clickable, for example if I return false for OnTouch() the button clicks however slide doesn't work, if I return true nothing happens when any button is pressed. I want to create it so when someone swipes across the keys it clicks the button they are currently on and deselects the previous. Like swiping across a piano.